Understanding Limitations on Total Results with Vimeo API's Search Query Parameter
I have a small project in which I would like to display cards based on the data from Vimeo and I also want to have pagination on my component. The pagination should work even when there is a search query in the url, but it seems like if I add a query string as a parameter it limits down the total number of retrieved objects without any pagination.
I get all the data like this:
https://api.vimeo.com/users/${userId}/albums/${albumId}/videos
{
  "total": 1000,
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 25,
  "paging": {
    "next": "/users/userId/albums/albumId/videos?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "first": "/users/userId/albums/albumId/videos?page=1",
    "last": "/users/userId/albums/albumId/videos?page=40"
  },
  "data": [ { ...data here } ]
}

It fetches the data just fine with correct pagination, however when there is a search query parameter present in the url, the results will be limited to 25 (the default per_page value set by Vimeo) and there will be only one page with 25 results. It seems like the per_page limits the total number of queried objects.
https://api.vimeo.com/users/${userId}/albums/${albumId}/videos?query=music
{
  "total": 24,
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 25,
  "paging": {
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "first": "/users/userId/albums/albumId/videos?query=music&page=1",
    "last": "/users/userId/albums/albumId/videos?query=music&page=1"
  },
  "data": [ { ...data here } ]
}

I could set the per_page to 100, which is the maximum value, but what if I have more search results than that, for example 110?
So after setting the per_page to 100 we get:
https://api.vimeo.com/users/${userId}/albums/${albumId}/videos?per_page=100&query=music
{
  "total": 71,
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 100,
  "paging": {
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "first": "/users/userId/albums/albumId/videos?per_page=100&query=music&page=1",
    "last": "/users/userId/albums/albumId/videos?per_page=100&query=music&page=1"
  },
  "data": [ { ...data here } ]
}

So it seems like if per_page is smaller than the actual results number (total), it omits some search results from the end without paginating the data.
Any suggestion on this?
